PySpark filter action takes too long
I have base_df dataframe with only 4 records -
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|         RECORDS_001|         RECORDS_002|         RECORDS_003|         RECORDS_004|         RECORDS_005|         RECORDS_006|         RECORDS_007|      RECORDS_HEADER|     input_file_name|              ROW_ID|unique_batch_id|  FAILED_VALIDATIONS|VALIDATION_STATUS|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|{{01/01/2023, 06/...|{[{07/19/2022, 07...|{[{0.00, 99213, D...|{[{0.00, 0.00, 0....|{{100.00, 29495.0...|{{{B}, 06/30/2023...|{[{H0354, 0.00, 0...|{{1, 7, 16, 7, 1,...|s3://gov-solution...|3f92edbf-4af9-48a...|              0|MEMBER_ID is miss...|           FAILED|
|{{01/01/2023, 11/...|{[{08/29/2023, 08...|{[{0.00, 96401, C...|{[{900.00, 0.00, ...|{{1235.77, 4700.0...|{{B, 11/30/2024, ...|                null|{{1, 3, 6, 3, 1, ...|s3://gov-solution...|3f92edbf-4af9-48a...|              0|                null|           PASSED|
|{{01/01/2023, 06/...|{[{07/19/2022, 07...|{[{0.00, 99213, D...|{[{0.00, 0.00, 0....|{{100.00, 29495.0...|{{{B}, 06/30/2023...|{[{H0354, 0.00, 0...|{{1, 7, 16, 7, 1,...|s3://gov-solution...|3f92edbf-4af9-48a...|              0|                null|           PASSED|
|{{01/01/2023, 06/...|{[{07/19/2022, 07...|{[{0.00, 99213, D...|{[{0.00, 0.00, 0....|{{100.00, 29495.0...|{{{B}, 06/30/2023...|{[{H0354, 0.00, 0...|{{1, 7, 16, 7, 1,...|s3://gov-solution...|3f92edbf-4af9-48a...|              0|MEMBER_ID is missing|           FAILED|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------+

But when I perform a filter action on this dataframe, then after it takes too long for any action on the dataframe. Below is the filter operation I am trying to perform -
        print("before filter")
        base_df = base_df.repartition(16)
        print(base_df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
        print(base_df.show()) # output of this is what I have given above

       
        base_df = base_df.filter(base_df.VALIDATION_STATUS == 'PASSED')
        
        print("After filtering") # Till here the job runs within a minute, but after this it starts taking too long for below print statements
        print(base_df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
        base_df.select('FAILED_VALIDATIONS').show(truncate=False)

I am running this script in AWS Glue Job with Glue version 4.0 and worker type as G.8X.
Please let me know how can I optimize it.
Thanks !!

Why do you need number of partitions if i may ask?

Not needed its just I was checking the partition should not be 1. But even if I comment that it still takes too long for the last show() query

@SurajPandey Try to perform the filter before repartition. Also, instead of using 16 - try with a smaller number like 4 or 8 and see if it makes any difference in the timing.

The "filter" you are talking about is not an action! Your print(After filtering) will show immediately. The filter operation is running after your print stmt when u call the show method because the show method is an action. The issue you may missing is that spark has lazy evaluation. The real action is the show method. This means that your print output will show before and the computation of your filters afterwards. Also 4 rows and 16 partition does not make sense

if you have 4 records, why do you want 16 partitions?

Thanks for your replies. Can you please let me know how much partition is needed here for 4 records ? My current glue worker type is G.2x with number of workers as 2

@SurajPandey There is no fixed answer for this. As you have 2 workers and just 4 rows in your dataframe - you can try with just 2 partitions. Again it depends on many other factors like the number of cores per worker\executor etc. So, try a different number of partitions and select the one which provides the desired performance.
